# jQuery datatable not functional on templated page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, jquery, datatable

I have a visualforce page which makes use of a template. I am trying to use jquery datatable to add funtionality to the pageblocktable. My code works on just a normal non-templated visualforce page but once I add it to the page with the template it breaks. I have made sure that the right $component id is being returned by verifying in developer tools yet the page continues to break. Here is my code:

**the apex composition:**

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" docType="HTML-5.0" id="theSection">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.BF_theme, 'css/style.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js')}"/>





<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style>
    article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
        display:block;
    }
    INPUT[type='text'] {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>
    .closebtn {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
  <apex:composition template="Template_TopBar"/>
  <!--<div class="container"> -->
    <apex:composition template="Template_Header"/>
   <!-- <div class="content, w100"> -->
        <apex:insert name="zoneA"/>
   <!--</div> -->
    <apex:composition template="Template_Footer"/>
  <!--</div>-->
</apex:page>
```

**And here is the full page with the template**

```
    <apex:page Controller="CasesController" showHeader="false" docType="HTML-5.0" id="thePage">
<head>    
  <title>Cases</title>
</head>

<apex:composition template="MasterPage_FullWidthTest">
<apex:define name="zoneA"> 
<apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock">
                      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!MyCaseList}" var="mylist" id="thePageBlockTables" styleClass="datatable">
                          <apex:column headerValue="Case Number">
                          <apex:outputLink value="{!mylist.CaseNumber}">{!mylist.CaseNumber}</apex:outputLink>
                          </apex:column>
                          <apex:column value="{!mylist.CreatedDate}"/>
                          <apex:column value="{!mylist.Requested_By__c}"/>
                          <apex:column value="{!mylist.Subject}"/>
                          <apex:column value="{!mylist.Release_Type__c}"/>
                          <apex:column value="{!mylist.Status}"/>
                          <apex:column value="{!mylist.Priority}"/>
                          <apex:column value="{!mylist.Major_Release_Version__c}"/>
                          <apex:column value="{!mylist.OwnerId}"/>
                          <apex:column value="{!mylist.Type}"/>
                      </apex:pageBlockTable>

                  </apex:pageBlock>   

</apex:form>
</apex:define>
</apex:composition>

  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js')}"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="    {!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryDataTablesZip,  'jQueryDataTablesZip/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}"></script> 
 <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryDataTablesZip, 'jQueryDataTablesZip/css/jquery.dataTables.css')}"/>
                <style type="text/css">
                .sorting {
                background: #f2f3f3 url('{! URLFOR($Resource.jQueryDataTablesZip, 'jQueryDataTablesZip/images/sort_both.png') }') no-repeat center right !important;
                padding-right: 20px !important;
            }
            .sorting_asc {
                background: #f2f3f3 url('{! URLFOR($Resource.jQueryDataTablesZip, 'jQueryDataTablesZip/images/sort_asc.png') }') no-repeat center right !important;
                padding-right: 20px !important;
            }
            .sorting_desc {
                background: #f2f3f3 url('{! URLFOR($Resource.jQueryDataTablesZip, 'jQueryDataTablesZip/images/sort_desc.png') }') no-repeat center right !important;
                padding-right: 20px !important;
            }
            .sorting_asc_disabled {
                background: #f2f3f3 url('{! URLFOR($Resource.jQueryDataTablesZip, 'jQueryDataTablesZip/images/sort_asc_disabled.png') }') no-repeat center right !important;
                padding-right: 20px !important;
            }
            .sorting_desc_disabled {
                background: #f2f3f3 url('{! URLFOR($Resource.jQueryDataTablesZip, 'jQueryDataTablesZip/images/sort_desc_disabled.png') }') no-repeat center right !important;
                padding-right: 20px !important;
            }
            table.dataTable tr.odd { background-color: white; }
            table.dataTable tr.even { background-color: white; }
            table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_1 { background-color: white; }
            table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_2 { background-color: white; }
            table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_3 { background-color: white; }
            table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_1 { background-color: white; }
            table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_2 { background-color: white; }
            table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_3 { background-color: white; }
            .dataTables_length, .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info, .dataTables_paginate {
                padding: 3px;
            }
            </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready(function() {
            var dataTables = document.getElementById("{!$Component.thePage.theSection.theForm.thePageBlock.thePageBlockTables}");
            j$(dataTables).dataTable();
        } );
  </script>      
</apex:page>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What error messages are displayed in your web browser's console?

Comment: @MarkPond- sorry I should have updated this earlier. I found what the issue was. The template_header has some cdn video links that for some reason only plays nice with jQuery 1.7.2. I removed it from the page and got the dataTable working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the issue was. The template_header has some cdn video links that for some reason only plays nice with jQuery 1.7.2. I removed it from the page and the dataTable started working as expected. Thanks.